# Software License for project using .NET and Sql Server Express

Tags: licensing, .net, gpl, sql-server, wpf

I considering making my application open source on github. I don't intend to sell it (neither in binary form nor source code form). It probably isn't even useful to a lot of people except maybe for learning purposes.

The application is developed in .NET 4.5 (WPF). It doesn't use any external libraries. Only pure .NET libraries as provided by Microsoft. However, it is dependent on Microsoft Sql Server Express 2008.

I would like to license the application under the GPLv3 but I don't know if that will work because of the SQL Server requirement. If not, what would you recommend? Sorry, but I'm having difficulties understanding all this legal stuff.

Comment: Does your code use MS SQL Server directly, or do you go through a standard library, such as ODBC?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I'm using the Entity Framework to access the Database

Comment: This question already has an answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528931/using-closed-source-api-in-a-gpl-application